# how to download all the report from SSRS report

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2

I am new in this field and I am looking to download a single report, but it has more than 200 values in a drop down. Can you guide me how to download all the report with 200 values in one go.

[image: screenshot]

Let me give you an overview of what the data looks like:

There are 200 practices and each practices has 5 or 6 providers. I am new in healthcare industry. So, I need to manually click on each practice and each provider and click on the view report to see the report and then download the report. So, we have run the report and click to save in PDF for all 1000+ reports.

We use the standard version of SSRs and we don't have any Enterprise version of it.

Can you guide me what to do in this case? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to amend the report definition so that the filters allow for 'Select Multiple' that way you can select all in the drop downs.

So for example:
[image]

The option "Allow Multiple Values" would allow you to Select all of that parameter.

Comment: Matt, Can you explain more on it. So, that i can try to build on it

Comment: hello Matt, 

Thanks for quick reply. But i think, i use to run the report for all the values and then save the PDF file every time. if i select "ALL Multiple Values" then Server takes long long time to run the report.

Also, i look some article someone suggest me to create master view on top of this table. But i have no idea how to use this table.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a **data-driven subscription** to generate these reports. When you set up the subscription, you can provide a query that lists all the practices. When the subscription runs, it will generate a separate copy of the report using each practice as a parameter value.

You can set the subscription to email the reports or save them in a folder. This way, it doesn't matter so much how long it takes to run and there is much less manual work for you once you set it up.

Comment: Steven, thankd for your reply. Just wanted to confirm . Is this features avaliable om Standard edition also. What I study online , this features is only available on enterprise edition

Comment: Correct, this is only for Enterprise. Which might be a good reason to upgrade. Standard is "for non-critical workloads with minimal IT resources." https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-2017-pricing

Comment: Thanks Steven for your comment, I will look into it. Does master view solves MY problem

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what was meant by a master view, but it does not sound like it would help at all in your situation. Views typically do not increase query efficiency and it would do nothing to help generate separate reports.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use URL Access and pass in the parameter you want.

Go to `http://<server_name>/ReportServer/` and find the report you want.

Then tack on to the end the parameter name and value you want. `&param=val&param2=val2`

Then add the `&rs:Format=` command and put your desired extension like CSV.

e.g. `http://<server_name>/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?<my_report_path>&param=val&param2=val2&rs:Format=CSV`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/pass-a-report-parameter-within-a-url?view=sql-server-ver15

If you have a lot of parameters, then run this through for loop. Python may be easiest.